# How to call a 'parent' trait method in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, traits

This is my code

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller {
    use ResetsPasswords;
    public function postReset(Request $request){
        // do some stuff
        // ...
        return parent::postReset($request); // <-here is the problem
    }
```

The method `postReset` is present in `ResetsPasswords`, but the code I've written is looking for this method within the `Controller` class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller {
    use ResetsPasswords {
      ResetsPassword::postReset as traitPostReset;
    };

    public function postReset(Request $request){
        // do some stuff
        // ...
        return $this->traitPostReset($request); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `parent::postReset($request)` issues a fatal error is because its parent `Controller` class hasn't `postReset` method. The trait isn't considered as a parent in that case even if it has an implementation of `postReset()` method.

To work-around this, you can give it a different name:

```
class PasswordController extends Controller
{
    use ResetsPasswords;

    public function postResetPassword(Request $request) // <- giving it a different name
    {
        // do some stuff
        // ...
        return $this->postReset($request); // and calling ResetsPasswords::postReset
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Dave. Unfortunately changing the method name would break the polymorphism I am trying to implement.